# How to make a circle checkbox with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The design I have been given to try to match requires a checkbox to be a circle. I'm using Material UI with React.

Border radius does not work because the border of the actual icon is not the border of the visible checkbox.

I can't just use something like Font Awesome, because it needs to actually be checked and unchecked.

```
// Current Styling
const styles = theme => ({
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 4,
  },
  icon: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    fontSize: 25,
  },
  root: {
    color: cyan['A400'],
    '&$checked': {
      color: cyan['A400'],
    },
  },
  checked: {},
});

// Actual checkbox code
return (
  // Holds the individual step with edit icon and delete icon
  <>
    <ListItemIcon>
      {/* Checkbox */}
      <Checkbox
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={step.completed} 
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value="true"
        classes={{
          root: classes.root,
          checked: classes.checked,
        }}
      />
    </ListItemIcon>
```

I want to keep the working code of Material UI `Checkbox` but just change some styling to make the edges a perfect circle (like a radio button but with a checkmark in the middle.

Comment: I just started using material-UI. I understand your code but can you please tell me what does it mean `&$checked`? I know that `&` is used for the current element and `checked` is pseudo-class. But I am totally not getting what does mean of `$` here

Comment: I wish I knew for sure. It was more a copy and paste from the documentation situation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Material UI's `Checkbox` [supports custom icons](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/). There are circular [checked circle Material icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=check), and for the empty circle, you can cheat a bit and use the icon for `Radio` input (they are the same size, so it works perfectly):

```
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import CircleChecked from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircleOutline';
import CircleCheckedFilled from '@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle';
import CircleUnchecked from '@material-ui/icons/RadioButtonUnchecked';

…

<Checkbox
  icon={<CircleUnchecked />}
  checkedIcon={<CircleChecked />}
  …
/>

// or with filled checked icon:

<Checkbox
  icon={<CircleUnchecked />}
  checkedIcon={<CircleCheckedFilled />}
  …
/>
```

…and it looks like this (*foo* is `CheckCircleOutline`, *bar* is `CheckCircle`):

[image]

Comment: BTW how did you get that gif on stack?

Comment: @Hailee it's just a screen recording converted to gif and inserted as an image…

Comment: I'm getting a blank checkbox (goes away entirely) using your code. I have @material-ui/icons installed as well as the core. When <CircleUnchecked/> is outside of checkbox, it shows up as expected, but having it like this, does not work. Can you link to a codesandbox?

Comment: In codesandbox this works, so I'm really wondering now what the hell I'm missing on my side. everything is installed, link in index.html added. still no joy sending the <CircleUnchecked> to Checkbox

Comment: seems like, for some reason, the above used my "secondary" color, which was the same as the background, to create a nice "FU" when you clicked it, disappearing entirely and not showing the check. *sigh

Answer (score 13):

You can override the checked and unchecked icons of the `Checkbox` as explained in [this](https://mui.com/components/checkboxes/#icon) section. To make it round like the `Radio` button, you can use the following [material icons](https://mui.com/components/material-icons/#main-content):

```
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

import RadioButtonUncheckedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/RadioButtonUnchecked';
import RadioButtonCheckedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/RadioButtonChecked';
import CheckCircleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircleOutline';
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle';
import CircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Circle';
import CheckCircleTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircleTwoTone';
import CircleTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CircleTwoTone';
```

```
<Checkbox
  icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
  checkedIcon={<RadioButtonCheckedIcon />}
/>
<Checkbox
  icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
  checkedIcon={<CheckCircleOutlineIcon />}
/>
<Checkbox
  icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
  checkedIcon={<CheckCircleIcon />}
/>
<Checkbox
  icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
  checkedIcon={<CircleIcon />}
/>
<Checkbox
  icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
  checkedIcon={<CheckCircleTwoToneIcon />}
/>
<Checkbox
  icon={<RadioButtonUncheckedIcon />}
  checkedIcon={<CircleTwoToneIcon />}
/>
```

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

to see if I understood you and try this:

```
    class RadioButtons extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedValue: '',
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.state.selectedValue === 'a' ?
    this.setState({ selectedValue: '' }) :
    this.setState({selectedValue: event.target.value})
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Radio
          checked={this.state.selectedValue === 'a'}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value="a"
          name="radio-button-demo"
          aria-label="A"
        />
)}
```